# How do I join my data using an array of IDs

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table called Jobs which has column Assigned partners, which is an array of IDs. I want to join it with the table called Partners which has the ID of each partner.
I want to output the Job details with the names of assigned partners.

JOBS

| id | title | assigned_partners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | ["a12","b23"] |
| 2 | abc | ["b23", "c45"] |

PARTNERS

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| a12 | Mark |
| b23 | Zack |
| c45 | John |

Required Output

| id | Job title | Partners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | ["Mark","Zack"] |
| 2 | abc | ["Zack", "John"] |

I'm having trouble to join my data on the array of IDs. Could you please help ?

Comment: If possible, you should change your database model and use an intermediary table jobs_partners to model this n:m relationship. Having comma-separated lists in relational database systems is almost always a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JOBS.id,
       JOBS.title `Job Title`,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(PARTNERS.Name) Partners
FROM JOBS
JOIN PARTNERS ON JSON_SEARCH(JOBS.assigned_partners, 'one', PARTNERS.id)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

| id | Job Title | Partners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | ["Mark", "Zack"] |
| 2 | abc | ["Zack", "John"] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jb-pzFma)